# Datatable showing wrong pagination when get data from server

Tags: datatable, pagination, datatables

In my webpage, I am using `datatable` to show the records. But when I try to show the data, data showing correctly but the pagination count is wrong.

My code is

```
oTableSp = $('#specials-table').dataTable({
    "bProcessing": true,
    "bServerSide": true,
    "sAjaxSource": <myUrl>',
    "bJQueryUI": true,
    "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
    "iDisplayLength":25,
    "lengthMenu": [ 25, 50, 75, 100 ],
    "dom": '<"top"f>rt<"bottom row"<"col-md-3"l><"col-md-3"i><"col-md-6"p>>',
    "columns": [
    {
        data: "SpecialName"
    },
    {
        data: "SpecialFrom"
    },
    {
        data : "SpecialTo"
    },
    {
        data : "SpecialBanner"
    },
    //      {
    //          data : "TermsAndConditions"
    //      },
    {
        data: "Actions",
        "bSortable" : false,
        "aTargets" : [ "no-sort" ]
    }
    ],
    "oLanguage": {
        "sProcessing": "<img src='../assets/admin/img/ajax-loader_dark.gif'>"
    },
    "aaSorting": [],
    "aoColumnDefs": [
    {
        "targets": [0,3],
        "bSortable" : false
    },
    ],
    "dom": '<"top"f>rt<"bottom row"<"col-md-3"l><"col-md-3"i><"col-md-6"p>>',
    'fnServerData': function (sSource, aoData, fnCallback) {
        sSource = sSource;
        aoData.push({
            name: 'csrf_tbd_token', 
            value: tbd_csrf
        });
        $.ajax
        ({
            'dataType': 'json',
            'type': 'POST',
            'url': sSource,
            'data': aoData,
            'success': fnCallback
        });
    },
    'fnCreatedRow': function( nRow, aData, iDataIndex ) {
        $(nRow).attr('data-id',aData['Id']);
    },
    "fnRowCallback" : function(nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex){
        var html = status_html(aData["active"]);
        $("td:eq(4)", nRow).prepend(html);
    },
    fnDrawCallback: function( oSettings ) {
        $(".pagination li").removeClass("ui-button ui-state-default");
        $(".first.disabled, .previous.disabled, .next.disabled, .last.disabled, .fg-button.active").off( "click" );
        $(".first.disabled a, .previous.disabled a, .next.disabled a, .last.disabled a, .fg-button.active a").attr('href','javascript:void(0);');
        $.ajax({
            url: <myUrl>',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data:{},
            success: function(data){
                if(data.result == 1){
                    data.message = jQuery.parseJSON(data.message);
                    $.each(data.message, function(index, element) {
                        $('tr[data-id="'+element+'"]').find('.actions').prepend('<a class="approve-sp-all" data-status="1" href="#" title="Approve"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-med fa-thumbs-o-down" style="color:#FF0000"></i></a>');
                    });
                    $('#specials-table tr').each(function(){
                        var elm = $(this);
                        var data_id = elm.attr('data-id');
                        if(jQuery.inArray(data_id, data.message) === -1){
                            $('tr[data-id="'+data_id+'"]').find('.actions').prepend('<a data-status="0" href="#" title="Approved"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-med fa-thumbs-o-up" style="color:#3c763d"></i></a>');
                        }
                    });
                }
            },
            error: function(){

            }
        });

    }
});
```

When I look in to the inspect element section, it is showing

[image]

But There is only two records to show as there in the `aaData`. Am I missing something? Please let me know.

Any help could be appreciated

Comment: From what I understand, when you set serverSide to be true, it expects the information to be provided by the ajax response. Since you are not using the built ajax, it just does not know about paging,etc.  Take a look at https://datatables.net/manual/server-side

Comment: @Bindrid, Thanks for the reply. will check that

Comment: @Bindrid, the `sAjaxSource` is the ajax url and it is correct. Only the count is wrong

Comment: The server-side function is not returning the correct values in `iTotalRecords` and `iTotalDisplayRecords` - I suspect `1234` is hard-coded test data. Can you post the code for the function?

Comment: You are using an older version of DataTables?  I can post my most complicated table but its for version 1.10

Answer (score 0):

If you are still interested, this my table definition.  I have four identical tables, each in its own tab so I created an object that is used for each tab.  Below is the table definition I use.

This is for DataTable ver 1.10:

```
    HomePageTab.prototype.getDataTableDefinition = function () {
        var me = this;
        var wspath = getBasePath("ws/wsNeps.asmx/GetHomePageTPS")
        var emptyTable = { "emptyTable": "No records returned." }
        var tblId = this._$tblMyDataTable.attr("id");
        // My favorites tab a some minor differences.
        if (tblId == "tblMyFavorites") {
            emptyTable = { "emptyTable": "No favorites found.<br />To add a favorite,  navigate to a specific TPS,  right click on top node in Navigation Tree,  select 'Add to Favorites'." };
        }
        var btns = this.setUpRowbuttons();

        this._$tblMyDataTable.on("preXhr.dt", function () { window.workingIndicator.startWork(me.get_element()); });
        this._$tblMyDataTable.on("xhr.dt", function () { window.workingIndicator.stopWork(me.get_element()); });

        var  dataTableOptions = {
                    buttons: [{ extend: 'excel', text: 'Excel' }],
                    columnDefs: [{ targets: [0], width: '40px', className: 'dt-body-center' }
                                 , { targets: [1], width: '40px', className: 'dt-body-center' }
                                 , { targets: [2], width: '35px', className: 'dt-body-center' }
                                 , { targets: [3], width: '25px', className: 'dt-body-center' }
                                 , { targets: [4], width: '130px' }
                                 , { targets: [5], width: '250px' }
                                 , { targets: [6], width: '75px' }
                                 , { targets: [7], width: '50px', className: 'dt-body-center' }
                                 , { targets: [8], 'type': 'datetime', width: '70px', className: 'dt-body-center' }
                                 // special action buttons inside the row cell
                                 , { targets: [-1],  className: 'ButtonColumn', ordering: false, 'type': 'html', 'width': "50px",  'data': null,  'defaultContent': btns}
                    ],
                   // Names in columns section must match the database column name.
                    columns: [{ data: 'FundingActivity' , name:'FundingActivity' }
                              , { data: 'PerformingActivity', name:'PerformingActivity' }
                              , { data: 'FiscalYear', name:'FiscalYear' }
                              , { data: 'RevisionNumber', name:'RevisionNumber' }
                              , { data: 'TPSNumber' , name:'TPSNumber'}
                              , { data: 'Title', name:'TPSTitle' }
                              , { data: 'PMUse1', name:'PMUse1' }
                              , { data: 'Status', name:'LastUpdated' }
                              , { data: 'LastUpdatedToString', name: 'LastUpdated' }
                              , { data: null }

                    ],
                    pageLength: 15,
                    select: { style: 'single' },
                    searching: true,
                    "lengthMenu": [[5, 10, 15, 20, 30, 50, 75, -1], [5, 10, 15, 20, 30, 50, 75, "All"]],
                    paging: true,
                    // filter is included but hidden in favor of the search box at the top of the page.
                    dom: 'lfrtBip',
                    ordering: true,
                    order: [[0, 'asc']],
                    "language": emptyTable,
                    "serverSide": true,
                    "ajax": {
                        url: wspath,
                        data: function (ssp) {

                            // server side parameters (ssp) are documented at http://datatables.net/manual/server-side
                            // in addition to the ssp parameters, the name of the column is pulled from the table header column
                            ssp.tabType = me._tabType;
                            var parms = JSON.stringify({ parameterList: JSON.stringify(ssp) });
                            test = JSON.parse(parms);
                            test.parameterList = JSON.parse(test.parameterList);
                            return parms;

                        },
                        type: "POST",
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        dataType: "json",
                        error: function (a, b, c, d) { debugger; },
                        dataFilter: function (data) {

                            // the web method returns the data in a wrapper 
                            // so it has to be pulled out and put in the 
                            // form that DataTables is expecting.
                            var p = JSON.parse(data);
                            return JSON.stringify( p.d);
                        }
                    },

                    initComplete: function (settings, json) {

                        me._$tblMyDataTable.on("click", "tbody tr td:not(.ButtonColumn)", function (evt, ui, we) { me.navigateToTPSPlanner(evt, ui, we); });
                        dtTableInitCompleteCallback(settings, json);
                        $("#hdnSearchText_" + tblId).off();

                    }

        };
        return dataTableOptions;

    };
```

Answer (score 0):

We have an IIS/C# back end so I created some classes for what the datatable is expecting and providing (the request and the response)

```
  #region DataTable (jQuery plugin) related
// the object below are set up to match what 
// the DataTable jQuery plugin expects to see.
// DataTableParameters is set up to match what 
// the plugin sends.
// DataTableData is set up to match what 
// DataTable expects to get.

[Serializable()]
public class DataTableData
{
    private static readonly ILog nepsLog4Net = LogManager.GetLogger("Keport.NEPS.GeneralDataObjects.DataTableData");
    /// <summary>
    /// draw (usually 1) is used by DataTable 
    /// to process async calls in order
    /// in the case of when more than one call is triggered.
    /// </summary>
    public int draw { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Total records, before filtering (i.e. the total number of records in the database)
    /// </summary>
    public int recordsTotal { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Total records, after filtering (i.e. the total number of records after filtering has 
    /// been applied - not just the number of records being returned for this page of data).
    /// </summary>
    public int recordsFiltered { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Data to be displayed in the table
    /// </summary>
    public List<HomePage> data { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Need to know the total rows and total filter rows
    /// for the DataTable pluging to figure out paging.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="dt"></param>
    /// <param name="dtData"></param>
    public static void SetRecordProperties(ref DataSet dt, ref DataTableData dtData)
    {
        try
        {
            if (dt != null && dt.Tables.Count > 1)
            {
                if (dt != null && dt.Tables[1].Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    dtData.recordsTotal = DSUtil.GetIntFromNullDr(dt.Tables[1].Rows[0], "UnfilteredCount");
                    dtData.recordsFiltered = DSUtil.GetIntFromNullDr(dt.Tables[1].Rows[0], "FilteredCount");
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Error logged but not acted on.
            nepsLog4Net.Error(ex);
            dtData.recordsFiltered = 30;
            dtData.recordsTotal = 30;
        }
    }

}

/// <summary>
/// This object represents what the default search 
/// object, passed back by the client 
/// as part of the DataTable built in AJAX.
/// Each item is documented at their web site.
///  http://datatables.net/manual/server-side
/// </summary>
[Serializable()]
public class DataTableParameters
{
    #region "Properties"
        /// <summary>
        /// Passed directly to the return set.
        /// Used to kept the async calls in order.
        /// </summary>
        public int draw{get; set;}
        /// <summary>
        /// Number of rows to be shown on a page
        /// </summary>
        public int length { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// tab type is used to determine if canned search should be used.
        /// </summary>
        public HomePage.Tabs tabType { get; set; }

        public SearchFor search { get; set; }
        /// <summary>
        /// the row number of used for the starting point 
        /// in creating a page
        /// </summary>
        public int start { get; set; }

        public List<column> columns { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Sort ordering information to be applied after filtering.
        /// </summary>
        public List<OrderByColumn> order;



    #endregion
        public struct column
        {
            public String data;
            public String name;
            public Boolean orderable;
            public Boolean searchable;
            public SearchFor search;

        }

        public class OrderByColumn
        {
            // column number 
            // db column name can be pulled from the 
            // column object name property
            public int column { get; set; }
            // sorting direction (asc or desc)
            public String dir { get; set; }

        }

        public struct SearchFor
        {
           public Boolean regex;
           public String value;
        }
}
#endregion
```